# Using the result of JSON in PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Complete rewrite of my question

The task I am trying to do is update the display of five variable without reloading the whole page.

I have a php file (check_conf_update.php) which runs a query that produces data and I am scripting it into JSON.
In the PHP file that runs the query I have at the end:

```
echo json_encode($record);
```

The JSON result looks like this:

```
[{"ClientName":"Another","RoomFromDateTime":"2016-02-25 01:00:00","RoomToDateTime":"2016-03-13 23:00:00","ClientImageName":"anothernew.png","DisplayText":"System Testing"}]
```

I now need to use the data on a page called "template.php). How can I read the data from the Json result and assign each of the result elements in variables I can use on my "template.php" page. I need the Json script to run every x seconds so the display is always shows up todate information.

I have five php variables:

```
$CientName
$ImageName
$DisplayText
$FromTime
$ToTime
```

which I use on my web page to display the data on the same page as the script below.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function runupdate() { 
       $.ajax({ 
         url: 'check_conf_update.php',
         type: 'GET',
         data: 'record',
         dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 
                // not sure what I need to do here
             } 
         });  
    };  

    // run it initially
    runupdate();

    // run it every 30 seconds
    setInterval(runupdate, 30 * 1000);
});
```

Sorry if have confused anyone, and it looks like I did.

Can anyone help. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Regards

Comment: So where would these values come from? There is nothing shown in your javscript or html to know what you want to post

Comment: Hi, What I am tring to do is get the data from mysql which I have already done and then use the JSON result in the PHP variables. I think the POST in the jquery should be GET.

Comment: creation of PHP variables aren't possible, but instead you will be able to result individual values like data[0].ClientName would return you with "Another"

Comment: So what is the specific problem...how to create the array in php to send as json?

Comment: specify what you wanna do with PHP variables?

Comment: Hi, data[0].ClientName would return you with "Another" I want to be able to display the content of data[0] in a php variable so I can then echo the content.

Comment: I think you are confusing php and javascript which run in completely different environments and at different times. Is the json shown what you want to deliver? If so what do you want to create or do with it in the page in browser?

Comment: Hi The JSON is the code I want to display in the web page. What I am trying to do is call data updates from the database without the page reloading. This is why I am trying to do it with JQuery, Ajax and JSON. Or am I approaching this totally wrong?

Comment: Hey, unless you specify exactly your intention with the variables, i have two advises for you. First PHP is executed by the server, so JavaScript which is executed by the browser will not help too much here. The second consider using a JSON Helper, there are too many of them online which are open source. I would greatly help you but as i told you, the info you're providing are not enough, i can help you on skype if you don't want to share too much. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear on what happens in your PHP script that produces the data. If you can update the post with the complete code for PHP also, it would be helpful. However, I'm assuming you want to use the data in the produced json string to populate the PHP variables in the destination file (check_conf_update.php)? In this case,

```
// check_conf_update.php
// $_POST['record'] == '[{"ClientName":"Another","RoomFromDateTime":"2016-02-25 01:00:00","RoomToDateTime":"2016-03-13 23:00:00","ClientImageName":"anothernew.png","DisplayText":"System Testing"}]'

$json = $_POST['record'];
$array = json_decode($json, true)[0];

$ClientName = $array['ClientName'];
$ImageName = $array['ClientImageName'];
$DisplayText = $array['DisplayText'];
$FromTime = $array['RoomFromDateTime'];
$ToTime = $array['RoomToDateTime'];

echo $ClientName . ', ' . $ImageName . ', ' . $DisplayText . ', ' . $FromTime . ', ' . $ToTime;
```

**Edit:**

All the PHP code in the `template.php` file is run on the server side before its rendered in the browser, so it will be too late to assign the updated json data into PHP variables by then. The only way to update information without reloading the page is to replace text or elements with javascript. After each successful ajax request, you can update the values in the page,

```
$('.clientname').html(data[0].ClientName);
$('.childbox').html(data[0].ClientImageName);
$('.clientndisplaytext').html(data[0].DisplayText);
$('.clientndisplaytime').html(data[0].RoomFromDateTime);
$('.clientndisplaytime').html(data[0].RoomToDateTime);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your replies. I have completely rewritten the question to try and make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: All the PHP code in the `template.php` file is run on the server side before its rendered in the browser, so it will be too late to assign the updated json data into PHP variables by then. The only way to update information without reloading the page is to replace text or elements with javascript. After each successful ajax request, you can update the values in the page, like for example `$('.client-name').html(data[0].ClientName);`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time solving my issue. I have used the code you kindly provided and as you say it works. If I then use the following data[1],data[2],data[3] and data[4] do not. This is how I have it in the scripts. $('.clientname').html(data[0].ClientName);
      $('.childbox').html(data[1].ClientImageName);
      $('.clientndisplaytext').html(data[2].DisplayText);
      $('.clientndisplaytime').html(data[3].RoomFromDateTime);
      $('.clientndisplaytime').html(data[4].RoomToDateTime);. I have all the DIV's in place.

Comment: In Chrome debugging I get the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClientImageName' of undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: The Uncaught TypeError occurs because data[1] is not set. All values are inside data[0], see my edit above.